# How can I override the index view (sites.py) for Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views

I want to override the index view present in `class AdminSite` in `django.contrib.admin.sites`. What I want to do through this is I want to check here if user is superuser then show index.html template with all models otherwise if user is an normal staff user then show him/her a test.html template with different content.

Answer (score 1):

The auth package lets you set up permissions on a model-by-model basis out of the box. There's not necessarily a need to override the view. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#permissions

Comment: But still If i ever need to override this view how can i do it?